# Trouble update-rc.d remove'ing dnsmasq on Debian Stretch

Tags: dns, services, dependencies, dnsmasq, rc

Background: On my Debian Stretch machine at home, I've noticed my DNS lookup times are pretty slow, and have concluded that the culprit is dnsmasq - since if I take it down, name resolution becomes > 10x faster (no multi-second delays). Now, it's probably some misconfiguration, but I was lazy and wanted to just remove it, since my router has a DNS server which is what dnsmasq is looking at anyway, and that's probably something like a dnsmasq of its own.

Anyway, I run:

```
update-rc.d remove dnsmasq
```

and get:

```
insserv: Service dnsmasq has to be enabled to start service apache2
insserv: Service dnsmasq has to be enabled to start service cups-browsed
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
```

My questions:

- Why would `apache2` and `cups-browse` depend on `dnsmasq`?
- Why am I running `cups-browsed` by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lazyness rules ;)

If you don't want to remove the program itself:

```
sudo update-rc.d -f dnsmasq remove
```

Comment: Even lazier - remove the exec flags(s) from `/etc/init.d/dnsmasq` to stop it from ever getting run.

Answer (score 0):

It's safe to remove `dnsmasq` from your home computer.

On my `Ubuntu 16.04` system, I disabled `dnsmasq`, and encountered the same problem in `cups-browsed` during `sudo apt-get update`.  I fixed it by running:

```
sudo nano /etc/insserv.conf.d/dnsmasq
```

after first commenting out the line `$named dnsmasq`.  (On my notebook, I simply deleted */etc/insserv.conf.d/dnsmasq*.)